# Insert data for geography data type in array php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sqlgeography

I have problem inserting geographic data into sqlserver database. This is my array:

this is my controller

**UPDATED**

```
  function add()
  {
    $Code = $this->input->post('Code');
    $Description = $this->input->post('Description');
    $Data= $this->input->post('Data');
    $Data2= $this->input->post('Data2');
    $Data3= $this->input->post('Data3');
    $Latitude = $this->input->post('Latitude');
    $Longitude = $this->input->post('Longitude');       
    $Highway_Type = $this->input->post('Highway_Type');

    $data = array(
    'Code' => $Code, 
    'Description' => $Description,
    'Data' => $Data,
    'Data2' => $Data2,
    'Data3' => $Data3,
    'Latitude' => $Latitude,
    'Longitude' => $Longitude,
    'Highway_Type' => $Highway_Type,
    'GeoLocation' => 'geography::Point('.$Latitude.', '.$Longitude.', 4326)',               
    );

    $parent_id = create_data('Table', $data, $user_id);
  }
```

The geolocation is the problem because it's geography datatype. I can't insert because I got this:

[this is screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIEkb.png)

How can I get rid of that thing `' '` for geography type shouldn't have that thing `' '`?

this is function for create data

```
function create_data($model_name, $data, $user_id)
{
    $ci =& get_instance();
    $ci->load->database();

    $ci->db->insert($model_name, $data);

    return $ci->db->insert_id();
}
```

Comment: what do you mean? you don't want to insert `geography::Point(2.992054, 101.769510, 4326)` ?

Comment: `geography::Point()` is it any method to get data.

Comment: @Dray i want to insert but i dont know how to get rid the upper colon ('geo..') in array

Comment: @farahdalilah array values are always enclosed with `' '` but it won't be saved in the db with `' '`. What do you want to save exactly? An example please?

Comment: dear @Dray I want to save this data 'geography::Point(2.992054, 101.769510, 4326)' into sqlserver . i have update my answer

Comment: Please note there's a clean distinction between strings and literals. You cannot use prepared statements to insert the latter. But there's no way to help you fix some code you haven't shared.

Comment: @farahdalilah show full code where you insert your array to DB.

Comment: Any error when you put it this way `geography::Point($Latitude, $Longitude, 4326),`?

Comment: @Tpojka yes, this is the error 'Fatal error: Class 'geography' not found' . don't know how to make it correct.

Comment: Do you have/use somewhere such a class?

Comment: @Tpojka I dont have any class of geography. because geography is a data type for sql server. is it should have a class for that?

Comment: No. My questions were here to denominate some CI regular errors. I just wondered if needed to execute some calculation before insert. It seems like string in table to me.

Comment: i dont really know about ci, sorry but i think it doesnt need calculation because its working when i insert manually in db something like this' insert into table (latitude,longitude) values ('01.000','101.000', geography::Point(01.000, 101.000, 4326))'

Comment: i have update my question @ÁlvaroGonzález is it okay?

Comment: i have update my question @Dray . is it okay?